extract text in different td in multiple excel cells in vba selenium web scraping
good morning sir, in web scraping with vba using selenium I would like to divide the text as in the part of the html code that I have reported below, extracted from the page, I would like to extract the nation, championship, matches played goals per match and so on (then once I understand the continuous process alone) as in the example I would like to extract "ENGLAND" , "PREMIER LEAGUE" ,"Matches played:" ,"319" , "Goals per match:" and so on, in consecutive cells on the same row, use "split " seems too cumbersome to me as there are too many spaces, at the moment I have only achieved the result of putting all the text that comes across the class "parent" attribute in a single cell in the first column.
Thank you


<tr class="parent" bgcolor="#f0f0f0" height="40" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;">
    <td colspan="8">
    &nbsp;
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...C4UQezUonUAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="16" height="11" alt="ENGLAND">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font size="2">England - Premier League</font>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a class="vsmall" style="font-weight:normal;" href="latest.asp?league=england">stats</a>
    </td>
    <td colspan="10" align="right">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;">Matches played: <b>319</b></font>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <font style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;">Goals per match:</font>
    ........
    ........
    ........
    ........
</tr>
    



this is my macro to extract the text I was telling you:
Sub example2()
Dim Driver As New selenium.ChromeDriver

Dim itab As WebElement
Dim td, tr As WebElement

Dim r, i, count As Integer

Cells.Clear
With Driver
    .Start
    .Get "https://www.soccerstats.com/matches.asp"
    
    
End With

    i = 1
        
        For Each tr In Driver.FindElementsByCss("tr")
            If tr.Attribute("class") = "parent" Then
              Cells(i, 1) = tr.Text
              i = i + 1
            End If
          
        Next tr
End Sub

